# Why is destructor of base class called from noexcept constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor, noexcept

Objects of class B are never deleted, so i want disable destructors, to save space.
I wonder, why is A::~A() used in B(), despite noexcept.

```
struct A
{
  A() noexcept {}
  ~A() = delete;
};

struct B : public A
{
  B() noexcept {}
  ~B() = delete;
};
```

g++-7 -std=gnu++1z says:

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
main.cpp:12:16: error: use of deleted function ‘A::~A()’
   B() noexcept {}
                ^
main.cpp:7:3: note: declared here
   ~A() = delete;
   ^
```

Comment: "so i want disable destructors, to save space" What? You seem to be confusing several concepts here, also object that you create will always be destroyed at some point (unless you leak *all* of them).

Comment: Can you clarify what space you're trying to save? Deleting the destructor takes extra space in the source code. And an unused function likely doesn't take any space in the executable. So what's to save?

Comment: Yes, this is duplicate, thanks to T.C.